# Angularjs / sailsjs :Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I am struggling on an issue with cors between angular js and sails.js (node.js framework)

I try to fix the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/en/auth/forgetpass/email. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

When I do not activate my interceptor it works well. I do not have this error. When I activate it, I have the error.

In my .config I setup the code below:

```
  //Enable cross domain calls
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS';

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
```

Then in my interceptor I setup the code below:

```
    return {
    request: function (config) {
      var id = Session.getprop('id');
      if(id) {
        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + id;
      }
        return config;
    }, ...
```

Finally, the result from the chrome network tab is:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:1337
Request URL:http://localhost:1337/en/auth/forgetpass/email
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK

Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,TRACE,COPY,LOCK,MKCOL,MOVE,PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,UNLOCK,REPORT,MKACTIVITY,CHECKOUT,MERGE,M-SEARCH,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,UNSUBSCRIBE,PATCH
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:154
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 12 Apr 2015 23:51:14 GMT
Set-Cookie:sails.sid=s%3A-bZxQgFntbDqTtaFyWDFFgFr.szR0F68VfIBjVW9kyans9d6v5fz7RMtalQCoMFdbH%2Fg; Path=/;   HttpOnly
X-Powered-By:Sails <sailsjs.org>

Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:access-control-allow-origin, accept, access-control-allow-headers, access-control-allow-methods
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:1337
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
```

And I still get the same error. An idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is an "interceptor"? That's not a sails.js concept.

Comment: Interceptor is an angularjs concept

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I finally found the issue.

I compared the response and request headers with interceptor and with it.

I change my code as below and it works.

In app.js of angularjs

I commented all the headers part.

```
   //Enable cross domain calls
  /*  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

//Remove the header used to identify ajax call  that would prevent CORS from working
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'origin, content-type, accept';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET,POST,PUT,HEAD,DELETE,OPTIONS';*/

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('TokenInterceptor');
```

And in my sails.js cors setup config I commented methods and headers. And it works well.

```
    module.exports.cors = {

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Allow CORS on all routes by default? If not, you must enable CORS on a   *
  * per-route basis by either adding a "cors" configuration object to the    *
  * route config, or setting "cors:true" in the route config to use the      *
  * default settings below.                                                  *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

   allRoutes: true,

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Which domains which are allowed CORS access? This can be a               *
  * comma-delimited list of hosts (beginning with http:// or https://) or    *
  * "*" to allow all domains CORS access.                                    *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

   origin: '*',

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Allow cookies to be shared for CORS requests?                            *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

   credentials: true

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Which methods should be allowed for CORS requests? This is only used in  *
  * response to preflight requests (see article linked above for more info)  *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  // methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Which headers should be allowed for CORS requests? This is only used in  *
  * response to preflight requests.                                          *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/

  // headers: 'origin, content-type, accept'

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the **origin** and **methods** in /config/cors.js ?

and also you can find more information on this page [Sails.Config.CORS](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.cors.html)

Comment: The link currently goes to a 404 page, I believe this may be what you want for v0.12
https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors
or https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors for v1.0